# How to recreate EC2 instances of an autoscaling group with terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, terraform

*Scenario:* I am running an AWS autoscaling group (ASG), and I have changed the associated launch configuration during terraform apply. The ASG stays unaffected.

How do I recreate now the instances in that ASG (i.e., replace them one-by-one to do a rolling replace), which then is based on the changed/new launch configuration?

*What I've tried:* With terraform [taint](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/taint.html) one can mark resources to be destroyed and recreated during the next apply. However, I don't want to taint the autoscaling group (which is a resource, and single instances are not in this case), but single instances in it. Is there a way to taint single instances or am I thinking in the wrong direction?

Comment: Why do you want the ASG to stay unaffected? The normal use case in this situation is to rolling replace the ASG and the instances inside it.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR yes, what I ultimately want to achieve is to replace them one-by-one (aka restack them or do a rolling replace). It's confusing that I talked about a single instance, so I update the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The normal thing to do here is to use [Terraform's lifecycle management](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#create_before_destroy) to force it to create new resources before destroying the old ones.

In this case you might set your launch configuration and autoscaling group up something like this:

```hcl
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "as_conf" {
    name_prefix = "terraform-lc-example-"
    image_id = "${var.ami_id}"
    instance_type = "t1.micro"

    lifecycle {
      create_before_destroy = true
    }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "bar" {
    name = "terraform-asg-example-${aws_launch_configuration.as_conf.name}"
    launch_configuration = "${aws_launch_configuration.as_conf.name}"

    lifecycle {
      create_before_destroy = true
    }
}
```

Then if you change the `ami_id` variable to use another AMI Terraform will realise it has to change the launch configuration and so create a new one before destroying the old one. The new name generated by the new LC is then interpolated in the ASG name forcing a new ASG to be rebuilt.

As you are using `create_before_destroy` Terraform will create the new LC and ASG and wait for the new ASG to reach the desired capacity (which can be configured with health checks) before destroying the old ASG and then the old LC.

This will flip all the instances in the ASG at once. So if you had a minimum capacity of 2 in the ASG then this will create 2 more instances and as soon as both of those pass health checks then the 2 older instances will be destroyed. In the event you are using an ELB with the ASG then it will join the 2 new instances to the ELB so, temporarily, you will have all 4 instances in service before then destroying the older 2.

Comment: I had min, max, and desired capacity set all to 1 before. I changed this now to 1, 2, and 1 based on your answer. However, I cannot observe your explained behaviour of creating another instance and destroying then the old one. Instead nothing happens, although terraform has created the new LC and modified the old ASG. I also waited to pass the grace period, and create_before_destroy was already set.

Comment: Note, it replaces the whole ASG, not the instances in it. So you will temporarily have 2 ASGs each with the minimum amount of instances in them. Once the second ASG has passed health checks Terraform will begin to destroy the older ASG.

Comment: This is interesting, terraform only modifies the old ASG (no additional on is temporarily created).  Sure I don't need to set other arguments to the ASG to achieve the behaviour you are observing?

Comment: Did you use the second lifecycle configuration block in the ASG as well? From memory it works as I described but I'd need to knock something together to check if you don't think that's actually happening.

Comment: You are right. The small but import difference was that the "name" of the ASG was not dynamic (i.e., based on the one of the  LC) in my case. However, terraform never complained. Only when I tainted the ASG and forced terraform to create a new one, it showed the error "AutoScalingGroup by this name already exists", which gave me the hint.

Comment: I have a followup question regarding this approach. I am using ECS with multiple services running using instances my ASG. I can make sure that all new instance will have the containers ready to go in the AMI. But when Terraform terminates the old ASG, the ECS cluster is still trying to spawn the containers in the new ASG. This will not guarantee zero downtime deploys. Any alternatives ?

Comment: Are you saying that the containers haven't yet spun up before the old instances and ASG are removed? It probably needs a separate stand alone question but the answer will likely involve using ELB health checks.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot solve this with terraform alone. Please see this AWS document (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/LaunchConfiguration.html):

> When you change the launch configuration for your Auto Scaling group, any new instances are launched using the new configuration parameters, *but existing instances are not affected*.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer per se, but I struggled with this as well. In one context it was general, in another, Kubernetes.

I ended up writing an open-source service to watch and auto-rolling update. It should solve this, but it is new, more than happy to get feedback/issues/PRs on it.

https://github.com/deitch/aws-asg-roller