# terraform force destory/add ASG instead of change on dependency change

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

For example, to force an auto-scaling group to be destroyed and added new, you can interpolate a dependency into the auto-scaling group name as described at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39347640/1007353

However, if you don't want to change the name, then this won't work.

Is there any way to force destroy/add an auto-scaling group without changing the name?

Is there a general way to force terraform to destory/add, like a force destory/add or taint variant of `depends_on`?

Comment: I can't think of a way for Terraform to automatically do this but is there any reason why you don't want the name of the ASG to change? I've been pretty happy using the name prefix of the LC and then having it generate randomness after that so you get a new name but still useful for identifying what the LC and ASG are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no way to force Terraform to re-create an ASG except to change one of its attributes that forces a new resource to be created. The `name` is what people usually use, as you've seen.

Changing the name has the advantage that it becomes possible to use the `create_before_destroy` lifecycle mode like this:

```
lifecycle {
  create_before_destroy = true
}
```

In this case Terraform will create the new ASG first, wait until it has successfully initialized, and only then destroy the old ASG. This would not be possible without changing the name since otherwise the two ASGs would have conflicting names.

Note that it's possible to avoid the need to *manually* specify a name by instead including in the name something that changes when the ASG needs to be replaced. A common choice, for example, is to include the AMI ID, assuming that this is already being populated from a variable interpolation and thus it can be interpolated into both the name and the AMI at once:

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "example" {
  name = "example-${var.ami_id}"
  image_id = "${var.ami_id}"

  # ...
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "example" {
  name = "${aws_launch_configuration.example.name}"

  launch_configuration = "${aws_launch_configuration.example.name}"

  # ...
}
```